# C# Enums - Check Flags against a Mask

Tags: c#, .net, enums, flags, enum-flags

I have the following enum flags:

```
[Flags]
private enum MemoryProtection: uint
{
    None             = 0x000,
    NoAccess         = 0x001,
    ReadOnly         = 0x002,
    ReadWrite        = 0x004,
    WriteCopy        = 0x008,
    Execute          = 0x010,
    ExecuteRead      = 0x020,
    ExecuteReadWrite = 0x040,
    ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x080,
    Guard            = 0x100,
    NoCache          = 0x200,
    WriteCombine     = 0x400,
    Readable         = (ReadOnly | ReadWrite | ExecuteRead | ExecuteReadWrite),
    Writable         = (ReadWrite | WriteCopy | ExecuteReadWrite | ExecuteWriteCopy)
}
```

Now i have an enum instance that I need to check if it's readable. If I use the following code:

```
myMemoryProtection.HasFlag(MemoryProtection.Readable)
```

It always returns false in my case because I think HasFlag check if it has every flag. I need something elegant to avoid doing this:

```
myMemoryProtection.HasFlag(MemoryProtection.ReadOnly)         ||
myMemoryProtection.HasFlag(MemoryProtection.ReadWrite)        ||
myMemoryProtection.HasFlag(MemoryProtection.ExecuteRead)      ||
myMemoryProtection.HasFlag(MemoryProtection.ExecuteReadWrite)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Requires .NET 4.0 or later

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can turn the condition around, and check if the composite `enum` has the flag, rather than checking the flag for the composite, like this:

```
if (MemoryProtection.Readable.HasFlag(myMemoryProtection)) {
    ...
}
```

Here is an example:

```
MemoryProtection a = MemoryProtection.ExecuteRead;
if (MemoryProtection.Readable.HasFlag(a)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Readable");
}
if (MemoryProtection.Writable.HasFlag(a)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Writable");
}
```

This prints `Readable`.

Comment: Readers should note that `HasFlag` became available with .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

Try bitwise operators:

```
[TestMethod]
public void FlagsTest()
{
    MemoryProtection mp = MemoryProtection.ReadOnly | MemoryProtection.ReadWrite | MemoryProtection.ExecuteRead | MemoryProtection.ExecuteReadWrite;
    MemoryProtection value = MemoryProtection.Readable | MemoryProtection.Writable;
    Assert.IsTrue((value & mp) == mp);
}
```

Comment: This is the preferred method if you have implemented a bit-mask approach.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `hasFlag` checks if every bit field (flag) is set.

Rather than treating `Readable` as a composite of all the protections that include `Read` in the name, can you turn the composition around?  E.g.

```
[Flags]
private enum MemoryProtection: uint
{
    NoAccess         = 0x000,
    Read             = 0x001,
    Write            = 0x002,
    Execute          = 0x004,
    Copy             = 0x008,
    Guard            = 0x010,
    NoCache          = 0x020,
    ReadOnly         = Read,
    ReadWrite        = (Read | Write),
    WriteCopy        = (Write | Copy),
    // etc.
    NoAccess         = 0x800
}
```

Then you can write code like:

```
myMemoryProtection.HasFlag(MemoryProtection.Read)
```