# How to know if enum has all flags

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I'm trying to know if a enum value has defined all flags. The enum is defined as following:

```
[Flags]
public enum ProgrammingSkills
{
    None = 0,
    CSharp = 1,
    VBNet = 2,
    Java = 4,
    C = 8,
}
```

I **cannot change the enum** to define 'All', because that enum is defined in a dll library.

Of course I can **iterate over all enum** values, but is there any better/shorter/smarter way to determine if a enum value has defined ALL values?

---

EDIT:

I would like to have working code even the enum changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204519/c-sharp-enums-check-flags-against-a-mask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it's better but it is definitely shorter and will work if you modify the `enum` in the future:

```
bool result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProgrammingSkills))
      .Cast<ProgrammingSkills>()
      .All(enumValue.HasFlag);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
var hasAll = val == (ProgrammingSkills.CSharp | ProgrammingSkills.VBNet
    | ProgrammingSkills.Java | ProgrammingSkills.C);
```

Or shorter, but not really good for maintenance:

```
var hasAll = (int)val == 15; // 15 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8
```

Or in a generic way:

```
var hasAll = (int)val == Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProgrammingSkills))
                             .OfType<ProgrammingSkills>().Sum(v => (int)v);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgrammingSkills ps = ProgrammingSkills.None | ProgrammingSkills.CSharp | ProgrammingSkills.VBNet | ProgrammingSkills.Java | ProgrammingSkills.C;

int total = (int)ps;

if (total == 15) return true;//ALL FLAGS THERE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test for all members:

```
bool allSet = value & (ProgrammingSkills.CSharp
                    | ProgrammingSkills.VBNet
                    | ProgrammingSkills.Java
                    | ProgrammingSkills.C) != 0;
```

The `|` creates a mask containing all possible values, which is tested (`&`) against `value`, containing the enum you want to test.

But that is error-prone and isn't really maintainable. You might want to stick to a loop.

Comment: I can only assume the down vote is for missing `ProgrammingSkills.C`?  But you clearly get the point across.

Comment: Reading the code, I'd think this just test if *any* of the bits are set instead of *all*.

Comment: @Dejan you appear to be right. To test for _all_ values, the `&` should become an `==` and the `!= 0` can be dropped.

Answer (score -1):

You can cast your enum to `int` and check if the value than is 15 (sum of all enum-flags):

```
ProgrammingSkills programmingSkills = ProgrammingSkills.CSharp | ProgrammingSkills.VBNet | ProgrammingSkills.Java | ProgrammingSkills.C;
int programmingSkillsValue = (int)programmingSkills;
if(programmingSkillsValue == 15)
{
  // All Flags are set
}
```